# What's the best way of using pointers in tween system?

Tags: c#, pointers, unity-game-engine

I use Unity and I need to create tween system to which I will pass the parameter and it will control it by itself. For example:

```
Tween tween = new Tween( "tween_move_x", 0.0f, 10.0f, 1.5f, someGameObject.transform.position.x );
```

And that code will automatically set values to passed param: someGameObject.transform.position.x from 0.0f to 10.0f by 1.5 seconds.

I am beginner and I don't understand what kind of pointers should I use in c# for this task. I tried to use something like this:

```
float *controlledParamValue;
```

but it says I need to use unsafe and fixed blocks. I think it's not the best idea to use it for that issue. I just want to link my controlledParamValue to someGameObject.transform.position.x for setting its values automatically from the Tween class. What should I use here?

Comment: C# [doesn't allow pointers by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/), so this question is fundamentally ill-posed. There's no way to maintain a reference to the memory value that the Vector3's x integer occupies. You're better off holding a reference to the *transform* and having another parameter (or two) to indicate that you wish to tween only the x value of its position.

Comment: As an aside, if you are looking for a quick tween system, I highly recommend DOTween. There's a free version that is fully functional where C# scripting is concerned.

http://u3d.as/aZ1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pointers in C#, you just need to use the `ref` keyword.

For example:

**Tween class**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Tween {

    public Tween (ref float tweenFloat, ref Vector3 tweenVector) {
        tweenFloat = 0.7f;
        tweenVector = new Vector3(0.6f, 1, 12.3f);
    }
}
```

**TweenTest class**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TweenTest : MonoBehaviour {

    float myFloat = 0;
    Vector3 myVector = Vector3.zero;
    Tween myTween;

    void Start () {
        myTween = new Tween(ref myFloat, ref myVector);     
        Debug.Log(myFloat);
        Debug.Log(myVector);
    }
}
```

If you attach `TweenTest` to a game object and run the scene, the output will be this:

```
0.7
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

(0.6, 1.0, 12.3)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

As you can see, even though `float` and `Vector3` are value types, by using the `ref` keyword you passed the reference to those variables instead of the value (which is the default behaviour when passing value types as parameters to methods/constructors).

This is the first step.

The second step is to remember that `transform.position.x` (and `y` and `z`) has only the `get` propriety, so you can't change its value directly, but you can change the `position` struct as a whole.
So, if you need to tween only the x component of the struct, and your `Tween` class accepts a `float` type:

```
Vector3 positionVector = transform.position;
myTween = new Tween(*your other parameters*, ref positionVector.x);
transform.position = positionVector;
```